# ¿Como comprobar un rango de valores en laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

Buenas, tengo un duda: quiero saber cómo puedo comprobar que mi estado esté en 1 o en 2 dentro de las credenciales de laravel.

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return array_merge($request->only($this->username(), 'password'), ['state' => 1]);
    //return $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
}
```

Este es el código que uso, quiero que state sea mayor o igual que 1

Answer (score 0):

Tal y como está construido Laravel, se puede y no se puede.

Se pueden añadir condiciones adicionales tal y como lo muestras en tu código. No una, sino varias, pero...

No se pueden poner condiciones diferentes a `'='` ni repetir el campo (columna) con valores diferentes ya que el `foreach` que convierte el array de condiciones en un `$query->where($key, $value);` se carga/machaca las llaves duplicadas en el `array` de condiciones. Si como alternativa se te pasó, como a mi, por la cabeza hacer algo parecido a `['state' => 1, 'state' => 2]`, no sirve de nada, dado que en una llave duplicada se queda con el segundo valor.

Una alternativa es modificar la función `retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)` del archivo `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php`

donde pone:

```
foreach ($credentials as $key => $value) {
            if (! Str::contains($key, 'password')) {
                    $query->where($key, $value);
            }
        }
```

tiene que quedar:

```
foreach ($credentials as $key => $value) {
            if (! Str::contains($key, 'password')) {
                if(is_array($value)) {
                    $query->whereIn($key, $value);
                } else {
                    $query->where($key, $value);
                }
            }
        }
```

De tal forma que puedas añadir condiciones en array:

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return array_merge($request->only($this->username(), 'password'), ['state' => [1, 2, 3]]);
    //return $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
}
```

Para hacer este cambio puedes seguir las instrucciones en esta pregunta de Stack: [Laravel 5.4 EloquentUserProvider override validateCredentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44069557/laravel-5-4-eloquentuserprovider-override-validatecredentials/46224576#46224576)